# STDOUT: order different in bash shell vs. order when read using QIODevice

Tags: bash, qt, shell, stdout

I'm having issues with stdout ordering. I'm spawning an Altera QuartusII process which executes a tcl script using its built in Tcl interpreter and then quits.

When I run the process from command prompt on Windows and/or a bash shell on Linux, the stdout order looks like this:

```
Synthesizing
... lots of quartus_map and quartus_cdb messages ...
Fitting 
... lots of quartus_fit messages ...
```

However, when I spawn the process using Qt's QProcess and read the full stdout buffer when the process finished, the order looks like this:

```
... lots of quartus_map and quartus_cdb messages ...
... lots of quartus_fit messages ...
Synthesizing
Fitting
```

The tcl script I run looks something like this:

```
puts stdout "Synthesizing"
flush stdout
if { [ catch {qexec "quartus_map $proj -c $rev" } ] } {
     post_message -type error "Error: quartus_map failed: ${::errorInfo}"
     exit
}
if { [ catch {qexec "quartus_cdb $proj -c $rev --merge" } ] } {
     post_message -type error "Error: quartus_cdb failed: ${::errorInfo}"
     exit
}

puts stdout "Fitting"
flush stdout
if { [ catch {qexec "quartus_fit $proj -c $rev" } ] } {
   post_message -type error "Error: quartus_fit failed: ${::errorInfo}"
   exit
}
```

I have no idea why the order is different. Any help or ideas on how to get the correct ordering using QIODevice would be much appreciated. All messages are available on stdout, there is nothing on stderr as expected.

EDIT:
It can be reproduced by this simple piece of code:

```
QProcess* process = new QProcess;
QStringList args;
args << "-t";
args << "test.tcl";
process->setWorkingDirectory("D:/work/fpga_designs/my_design");
process->start("C:/tools/Altera/Quartus/13.0/quartus/bin/quartus_sh", args, QProcess::ReadWrite);
if (!process->waitForStarted(30000)) {
    process->waitForFinished();
    return 1;
}
while (process->state() == QProcess::Running || process->state() == QProcess::Starting) {
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
process->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
QByteArray ba_stdout = process->readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug() << ba_stdout;
```

Comment: You have not shown your code.

Comment: Thanks, added Qt side code.

Comment: This is not enough code. We would need to see how you print and you start the process, etc.

Comment: Ok, added details on how QProcess is created and how messages are printed.

Comment: First time is waitForStarted(), not waitForFinished().

Comment: Your code is incomplete. We would need the whole ufnction, not just chunk of it. Either way, the `if (!d->process->waitForStarted(30000)) {` condition seems to be weird. It waits for finishing if it could not start. Why is that?

Comment: I've edited the post to contain a self-contained piece of Qt code which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try running your script on the command line on linux with `2>/dev/null`. I would not be surprised if Synthesizing and
Fitting is all you see, because the quartus_* processes write all their stuff to stderr. Not knowing anything about Qt I guess QProces:MergedChannels merges stdout and stderr, putting stderr first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it thanks to @Harald.

It was indeed due to the merged channel mode I used and the way Quartus puts all its messages on STDERR by default. STDOUT appears after STDERR in the buffer due to the way Qt does the merging.

The fix is to either not use merged channels, or to post messages on stderr:

```
puts stderr "Synthesizing"
flush stderr
```